# Accessing resource file from class path

Tags: java, web-services, classpath

I am trying to access my resource files from my class path. I have stored all my resources in a folder called "config" which has been added to my build path.
Now the problem is, i am unable to access them. I have tried following options, but none of them seems to work. Everything returns null.

```
String resourceName = "/config/LPANewCommonModelSchema.xsd";
System.out.println(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(resourceName));
System.out.println(getClass().getResource(resourceName));
System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(resourceName));

String resourceName = "config/LPANewCommonModelSchema.xsd";
System.out.println(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(resourceName));
System.out.println(getClass().getResource(resourceName));
System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(resourceName));

String resourceName = "/LPANewCommonModelSchema.xsd";
System.out.println(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(resourceName));
System.out.println(getClass().getResource(resourceName));
System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(resourceName));

String resourceName = "LPANewCommonModelSchema.xsd";
System.out.println(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(resourceName));
System.out.println(getClass().getResource(resourceName));
System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(resourceName));
```

EDIT:
Somebody asked for hierarchy,
[image]

Thanks in advance,
Harsha

Comment: Can you post the directory structure of the archive?

Comment: What type of project is it? Also, I asked for the *deployed* directory, not the project one. That is because usually the files are put in an archive and deployed onto the server, and in this process your file may not be where you think it is

Comment: It is a dynamic web project. Actually i haven't deployed it, it is in the development phase. Here only i am not able to access my resources from config folder. did i answer your question?

Comment: No :) if this is a web project, the wrong code is triggered by a client request. A client request means there must be a server somewhere, and this server must access your deployment

Comment: so you mean to say, the relative path is getting wrong because of the client request?

Comment: No, I'm saying this is not PHP. The directory structure of your project is no a 1:1 map of the deployed archive. Which server do you run? Can you describe your development process? (Kind of edit file, play green button, load page in browser...)

Answer (score 1):

Try with this (assume the current calss is beside resources folder)

> ```
> InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
>                                 .getResourceAsStream("config/LPANewCommonModelSchema.xsd");
> ```

or this

> ```
> InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/config/LPANewCommonModelSchema.xsd");
> ```